# How do I get a YouTube anchor to authorize my account

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on an application that can pull the live video of an authorized anchor for display. I want to know how to authorize. Do I get access token through oauth2 provided by Google. If there are 10 anchors, do I need to manage tokens for 10 people respectively.

In addition, I found that the Search API needs a quota of 100 to query video information of the channel. Is there any other alternative

Comment: if there public videos just use an api key

Comment: Could you precise more precisely what you are looking for when saying "query video information of the channel" ? You are looking to a list of videos uploaded on the channel, its playlists, details about videos ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.